# How to sort a Struct and for loop it using from to using a function in ColdFusion

Tags: struct, coldfusion

i to come out two string using `struct` but the data are not in ascending order. Besides that, i also want to for loop it using from to like loop from 1 to 50 but i only know to for loop using the array dunno how to for loop the `struct`. Anyone can help? I am in rush to finish it. TQ.
My code code is like below

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8" />
<cfset lang = structNew() />
<cfset lang.ch = structNew() />
<cfset lang.en = structNew() />
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer1"] = "代理 1">
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer2"] = "代理 2">
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer3"] = "代理 3">
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer4"] = "代理 4">
......
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer1"] = "Dealer 1">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer2"] = "Dealer 2">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer3"] = "Dealer 3">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer4"] = "Dealer 4">
.....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the latest release of ColdFusion, ColdFusion 2016, you can use `structNew("ordered")`.

*For ColdFusion 11 or earlier...*

You can maintain order of your structures by using Java's [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). One difference though is that LinkedHashMap is case sensitive so when defining a struct within a struct, you must use bracket notation (ie: `struct1["struct2"]`). It's good to also note that you can treat them much like a CFML structure in that you can use functions like `structKeyExists()` etc. on them.

```
<cfset LinkedHashMap = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap") />

<cfset lang = LinkedHashMap.init() />
<cfset lang["ch"] = LinkedHashMap.init() />
<cfset lang["en"] = LinkedHashMap.init() />

<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer1"] = "代理 1">
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer2"] = "代理 2">
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer3"] = "代理 3">
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer4"] = "代理 4">

<cfset lang["en"]["dealer1"] = "Dealer 1">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer2"] = "Dealer 2">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer3"] = "Dealer 3">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer4"] = "Dealer 4">

<!--- Example to see structure --->
<cfdump var="#lang#">
```

To loop over a structure, you can use the `collection` and `item` attributes...

```
<!--- Loop Example --->
<h3>CH Dealers</h3>
<cfloop collection="#lang['ch']#" item="dealer">
    <cfoutput><li>#dealer#: #lang['ch'][dealer]#</li></cfoutput>
</cfloop>

<h3>EN Dealers</h3>
<cfloop collection="#lang['en']#" item="dealer">
    <cfoutput><li>#dealer#: #lang['en'][dealer]#</li></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

You can test the above example at trycf.com -> [http://trycf.com/gist/c54d309a6012c97cb29a](http://trycf.com/gist/c54d309a6012c97cb29a/acf11?theme=monokai)

Comment: You may want to edit the answer to also display the value of the key. So, `<li>#dealer#</li>` becomes `<li>#dealer#: #lang['ch'][dealer]#</li>`. Which will show `dealer1: 代理 1` etc

Comment: @JohnWhish, Good call, changes made.